# Python how to delete empty row from list of dictionaries in a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries called "rows." However, this list contains some dictionaries with empty values (labeled as "None"). How could I write a for loop that goes through every row and deletes the entire row if it finds "None" in the key named 'lat'?

This is my list of dictionaries ("rows"). I'd like to write a for loop that deletes first row since 'lat' value is 'None.' Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[{'created_at': None, 'userid': None, 'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
 {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:34 +0000 2015', 'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, 
 {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:46 +0000 2015', 'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List Comprehensions is the way to go.

```
rows = [{'created_at': None, 'userid': None, 'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
 {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:34 +0000 2015', 'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, 
 {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:46 +0000 2015', 'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
rows = [ row for row in rows if row['lat'] is not None ]
```

You can read the 
[list comprehensions documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to learn more.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to check whether `row['lat'] is not None`?

Comment: @msemelman, excellent answer, thank you also for the references!

Answer (score 4):

If you are a beginner, an easy way to understand it is to define a function and remove them.

```
def deleteNone(rows):
    ret = []
    for item in rows:
        if item.get('lat', None) is None:
            pass
        else:
            ret.append(item)
    return ret

rows = deleteNone(rows)
```

Comment: You can `if item.get('lat', None) is not None:ret.append(item)` and forget the else.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to make it the closer to english possible, to make it easier for him to understand @PadraicCunningham thanks for the remark anyways!!

Comment: No worries,  `if item.get('lat', None) is not None:ret.append(item)` just looks a bit nicer ;)

Answer (score 1):

A universal way is to iterate it by index in reverse order. This makes sure that the indices will still be correct after removing items. By universal I mean that the same technique will work in any programming language.

```
   for n in range(len(list) - 1,-1,-1):
        if list[n]['lat'] == None:
            list.pop(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on having a non-Falsish `lat` attribute:

```
d = [{'created_at': None, 'userid': None, 'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
     {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:34 +0000 2015', 'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, 
     {'created_at': 'Mon May 04 04:35:46 +0000 2015', 'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
d = list(filter(lambda x: x["lat"], d))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect job for `filter`:

```
rows = filter(lambda d: d['lat'] is not None, rows)
```

Although if you can, it would be better to prevent getting those bad rows into your list in the first place!